# select tag of angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, select

I try to fill a select in angularJS but it doesn't work and I don't understand why.
So in my controller I use an http request to fill cShops property of an historic object. I use a Console.Dir() on my property to display the content and my variable is good filling. So I Tried to use this list of object to fill my select tag but it doesn't work and I haven't not errors in chrome console.

Method to get Historic with an property who contains a list of shops:

```
var reqGetHistEmployees = $http({ url: 'api/Employees/GetHistoryEmployee', params: { 'id': id } });
                reqGetHistEmployees.success(function (resolve) {
                    $scope.histEmployee = resolve;
                    console.log('histEmployee[0].cShops : ');
                    console.dir($scope.histEmployee[0].cShops);
                });
```

So when I verify the list, the shops are filled. So I tried to display this list in a select in my html:

```
Affectations :
        <table class="myTable">
            <thead style="background-color:#54a0fc !important;">
                <tr>
                    <th>{{'Shop' | i18n}}</th>
                    <th>{{'Function' | i18n}}</th>
                    <th>{{'Contract' | i18n}}</th>
                    <th>{{'Entrance' | i18n}}</th>
                    <th>{{'Ending' | i18n}}</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="hist in histEmployee">
                    <td><select ng-options="shop.Name for shop in hist.cShops track by shop.ShopID"></select></td>
                    <td>{{hist.FunctionName}}</td>
                    <td>{{hist.ContractName}}</td>
                    <td>{{hist.DateOfEntry | date:'shortDate'}}</td>
                    <td>{{hist.DateOfEnding | date:'shortDate'}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

but my select is empty and I haven't errors on console so i don't know how resolve this problem.

Thank you in advance for any assistance you could give me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an ng-model attribute inside your select tag.

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions. If my hint doesn't resolve your issus you might be missing something else. Read the docs - it should be a simple fix to do yourself.

**Update**
I guess you also want to store the shops ID on selection and want to display the Name for the user.

So you need to go for something like this:
**select** as **label** for **value** in **array**

Your select: id
Your label: name
Your value: shop
Your array: hist.cShops

Comment: Thanks, I doesn't know the second form of the select and it works.